# How to use emulator for a kivy App. But I do not know how to do that. Just trying to do a demo

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I built a kivy (kivymd) app and I want to do a demo. I would like to do that through an emulator. Anybody has any knowledge about that?

Comment: You can install Android Studio. Then use the included device manager to create a virtual device. You can install your app on that emulator to test it.